# Serialize XML into pdfConverter object

Tags: c#

I have a `pdfConverter` object (I added a reference to **EvoHtmlToPdf**).
I want to initialize the object with values from XML.
I tried to do deserialize but it doesn't work because the `pdfConverter` object
has some levels.
How can I initialize the object with all levels from the XML file?